# Selecting specific column in RowDataBound

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rowdatabound

I am trying to make it so that if there is a cell in a specific column that doesn't contain a value, i want that cell to change colour.

I don't currently have any example code that i can show but i would be grateful if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RowDataBound` Event should like this

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "open")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            else if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "close")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define a `GridView` in markup, like this:

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" emptydatatext="No data available." runat="server" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
    <Columns>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="CustomerID" headertext="Customer ID"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="CompanyName" headertext="Company Name"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="Address" headertext="Address"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="City" headertext="City"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="PostalCode" headertext="Postal Code"/>
      <asp:boundfield datafield="Country" headertext="Country"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note: Your `GridView`'s `DataSource` needs to have public property names that match the `datafield` values defined in your `GridView`.

Second, you need to implement the `onrowdatabound` event defined in your `GridView`, which points to a method named `GridView1_RowDataBound`, like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Put logic here to check particular cell value
        // Here is an example of changing the second cell (`Cells` collection is zero-based) to italic
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "<i>" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "</i>";
    }
}
```